# How to compare two lists filled with excel values the best way

Tags: c#, excel, list

I have two lists that hold values from two different Excel sheets and both lists hold numbers that identify a cell in the other Excel sheet so I have collected the data from the Excel sheets and now I want to check the numbers towards each other so I will get the correct value from the second Excel sheet on a combined Excel sheet with values from both of the other Excel sheets on the correct line so if I have some numbers like this

```
excelSheet1 List<string> number1 = {54378,52234,33780} 
excelSheet2 List<string> number2 = {"33780","52234","54378"}
List<string>valueThatIwhantPlacedCOrrectly = {"500","700","900"}
```

Wanted is a new Excel sheet in this style:

[image]

How do I check the equality between this and get the index so I can place the values correctly? I have tried this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < products.productId.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < products.prodPriceNumber.Count; j++)
    {
        if(products.productId[i] == products.prodPriceNumber[j])
        {
            Add the value to the Excel file
        }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't catch all the equal values.... What would be the best way to go about this? And avoid if there is any errors in the two first Excel sheets? Is the way I do it already the best or how would I do it?

Comment: Check how the formatting is set in excel for the cells that aren't matching.  Excel may be using General Formatting, or  truncating decimal places.

Comment: Please describe the problem briefly in the title. Somebody with the same problem is not going to see "how would I do this the best way?" as a possible answer to their problem.

Comment: How are you loading the data from Excel to your application? Are you just using Excel to show your example?

Comment: And "best way" requires a metric, e.g. laziest for me, smallest memory footprint, fastest runtime, ... .

Comment: Im using interop office library